# Alternative to nested cursor in AWS Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

How can we achieve nested cursor in aws redshift ? Can we use python or spark to achieve that functionality. 
Any other alternatives are welcome.
I found incompatibility on aws product support page.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/declare.html

Answer (score 0):

Currently **AWS Redshift** doesn't support opening more than one cursor during a sessions. Please find quote below from their official [cursor declare](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/declare.html) documentation:

> You must declare a cursor within a transaction block. Only one cursor
>   at a time can be open per session.

**Alternative:**

Pretty much your only alternative is to implement this logic in your application layer. Design some sort of python/script that would use local host machine resources to process the data. You could also offload that process to Redshift but that logic would would still need to be designed in the application layer.

Below is an example of how to read data from Redshift using Python and loop over it:

```py
import psycopg2

#Create connection
con=psycopg2.connect(dbname= 'dbname', host='host', 
port= 'port', user= 'user', password= 'pwd')

cur = con.cursor() #Create a cursor from the connection

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM table_name;") #Run the select you want to loop/cursor over

for row in cur:
    #do something with every single row here
    #optionally print the row
    print row

#Clean up cursor and connection by closing
cur.close() 
conn.close()
```